# Get Logged In user Image and Display it in the navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat, google-api-client

I am using google API to login I am getting the URL Of the person and his google plus photo , How do I save it in local so that I can Retrieve it and display it in my navigation drawer .

I used [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) tut for google Plus Sigin

and [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html) link for nav drawer

I need to show logged in user picture in the navigation drawer how can i do it ?

Thanks ,
Suresh kumar.V

```
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: :You have to convert this photo on base64 string and save this string in your local database and retrive from their.

Comment: when I try using that the app crashes :\

Comment: :What was the error?

Comment: I dont get an error i used that in onPostCreate and the app constantly crashes . There was no error in Log

Comment: :you just search on google that how to convert an image into base64 string stored and retrived from database.

Comment: edited the question to show how I convert to base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this You can use third party library like Picaso, Universal Image Loader or Volley through passing image url in it.

i recommned you to use Volley Library. and how to use Volley library.[**Here**](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) is the link.

so this way u can set images in navigation drawer's ImageView.
(if you are using Volley library then u can use NetworkImageView which is a custom imageview of Volley library instead of Imageview which is automatically make cache management).

And its very easy to use.

Comment: is there a way i could store it locally?

Comment: Yes you can do this with InputStream class and write that into External Drive with OutStream.  
**Example:**  
InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(image_url).getContent();